# Filter and sum Model with Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 models - Donations, People, Organizations

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :donatable, polymorphic: true
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :branch
   has_many :donations, as: :donatable
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :branch
   has_many :donations, as: :donatable
end
```

Donations can either be from people or organizations. People and Organizations are belong to branches.

I'm trying to filter the donations from a particular branch and total them, here is the scope I wrote :

```
scope :for_branch, lambda { |branch_id| 
    return nil  if branch_id.blank?
    joins(:donatable).where(:branch_id => branch_id)
}
```

It returns the error :

```
Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :donatable
```

How can I accomplish the task?

Comment: In which model are you adding this scope?

Comment: The model I am adding the scope into is Donations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to outer join all the `Person` and the `Organization` to the matching `Donation` (by restricting on the donatable_type).

Then you select all the `Donations` where any of the joined brach_id columns matches.

Outer joins must by specified as stirng with `.joins('..')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Donation.joins("left join persons on persons.donatable_id = donations.id").joins("left join organizations on organizations.donatable_id = donations.id").where('persons.branch_id=? OR organizations.branch_id=?', branch_id, branch_id)
```

If you need a scope

```
scope :by_branch, lambda { |branch_id|
   return nil  if branch_id.blank?
   joins: ["left join persons on persons.donatable_id = donations.id",
           "left join organizations on organizations.donatable_id = donations.id"],
   conditions: %('persons.branch_id=#{branch_id} OR organizations.branch_id=#{branch_id})
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work since People and Organizations are related by the polymorphic association donatable, and not donations :/

Here is the error : output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "people"

Comment: My bad...I was just editing my answer...I think you can go by @axel Tetzlaff's answer